# Concurrency checking on a REST API?

Tags: api, rest, concurrency

I'm starting a REST API to make a Web Application.

Most web sites tell you to delete resources issuing a `DELETE` HTTP request to an URI like `/{resource}/{resource-id}`. I'm afraid of deleting some resource that could have been updated since I retrieved it, or even a wrong resource.

Would it be OK to require sending the resource's timestamp along with the request? I haven't seen it anywhere, but I think it could be really useful. It would check for concurrency and prevent deleting random resources without even retrieving them before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the HTTP headers of [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) and [`If-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24) with your `DELETE` request.

The **client** `GET`s the resource:

```
GET /things/42
```

The **server** responds:

```
200 OK
ETag: "foo-bar-baz"
```

The **client** wants to `DELETE` the resource:

```
DELETE /things/42
If-Match: "foo-bar-baz"
```

**Case 1:** thing 42 was not changed, it can be deleted. The **server** responds:

```
410 Gone
```

**Case 2:** thing 42 was changed and does not match the `ETag: "foo-bar-baz"`. It is *not* deleted, the **server** reponds:

```
409 Conflict
```

**Variant:**

You can also use the headers [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and [`If-Unmodified-Since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.28) instead of or in addition to `ETag` and `If-Match`.

See the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml).

Comment: Thanks @Tichodroma, you really pointed me in the right direction! Wikipedia also helped while you were writing the full answer: [HTTP_ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Typical_usage).

Comment: @tinchou Then go get them, tiger :)